# Hook when an item is moved in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-hooks

I've been looking for a hook in drupal 7 that allows me to send an http request when the user moves a taxonomy term in or out of another taxonomy. For example:
[image]

I want to be able to 'detect' when I take `World War` in or out of `This is War`.
I hope you can help me, and sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone trying to achieve this, I found a way to do it. Not sure if it's the only one there is, but here it goes:

In your custom .module file, implement a hook with the following form Id

```
function mymodule_form_taxonomy_overview_terms_alter(&$form, $form_state)
```

Then, you can add a `#submit` element like this:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_handler';
```

Now, you can define `my_custom_handler` as follows

```
 function my_custom_handler($form, &$form_state)
```

And `my_custom_handler` will execute every time user saves changes in the specific form. If you need to get the terms in the `my_custom_handler` method you could somehow mimic the code in the source taxonomy module.
I hope someone finds this useful

Answer (score 0):

For "detect", `hook_taxonomy_term_update` may help you.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_update/7.x

Comment: For some reason, Drupal doesn't execute the taxonomy_term_update hook when performing that specific action, I already tried that one, but thanks.